# Why can't I see "Login" button on User record

Tags: administration, grant-login-access

I am trying to login to Salesforce as another user but I cannot see the "login" button usually found on the User record.

I am a System Administrator and have both the "Manage Users" and "Modify All Data" attribute setup on my profile.

The "Login Access Policies" only lists **Salesforce.com Support**

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: See the Checkbox here]Enable Administrators Can Log in as Any User on "Login Access Policies"

Comment: There is no such option as mentioned above.

Comment: Please refer the link here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Enabling-Organization-Admins-Can-Login-as-Any-User&type=1

Comment: Yeah option not showing up for me either, and I confirmed we have Enterprise edition